# Is it necessary to have a constant reward in the terminal state?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have downloaded the grid world project form this [link](https://github.com/srinadhu/RL_Pacman/blob/master/README.md). I have executed the project multiple times using:

```
python gridworld.py -k 20 -a q -r -0.2 -s 90
```

I have noticed that the reward of the terminal states are changing with time :
The grid world at time t -->

[image]

The grid world at some later time  -->

[image]

First of all, I am assuming that the values written inside the terminal states are the rewards and not the values of these states, since we don't have q values calculated for these states like the other states. If you see for example the green terminal state, at time t the reward is equals to 0.75 but after some time it has converged to 1 . So can we have a changing rewards in an episodic task ? If yes, why ?